# Similarity score sequence alignment

Tags: python, alignment, python-itertools, similarity, biopython

I have a list of sequences that I parsed from a superfamily of proteins. I want to compare these sequences to one another and check and calculate the sequence similarity. I do so by first pairing my sequences in the list with itertools.combinations. Then I use these to get a result_handle by doing NCBIWWW.qblast and subsequently parsing them. then I check for HSP in these alignments and try to calculate the number of matches/min(of the query and subject sequence). However, I always get a similarity score of a 100%, which shouldn't be correct.

```
pairs = itertools.combinations(filtered_list, 2)

for pair in pairs:
    query_sequence1, query_sequence2 = pair

    result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastp", "nr", query_sequence1)
    blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)
    
    for record in blast_records:
        for alignment in record.alignments:
            for hsp in alignment.hsps:
                match_ratio = len(hsp.match)/min(len(hsp.query), len(hsp.sbjct))

                print("****Alignment****")
                print("sequence:", alignment.title)
                print("length:", alignment.length)
                print("e value:", hsp.expect)
     print(f"Match ratio: {match_ratio:.2f}")
```

I was expecting the match ratio to be somewhere between 0.00-1.00, however, it is always 1.

Here's the output
[image: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lltaf.png)]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i76682974/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are blasting each individual sequence, and thus the results you are receiving are the top-most sorted (i.e., most similar) sequences returned by BLAST.

The Levenshtein distance metric has an existing extremely fast implementation written as [a Python library](https://github.com/maxbachmann/Levenshtein) (install simply via `pip install levenshtein`), and is the best distance metric to use for comparing strings of different lengths.

You are right in needing to first construct a pairwise (i.e., squared) matrix of your sequences to compare. The following code demonstrates an example in Python that bypasses any reliance on making calls to Blast and is quite fast:

```py
import itertools as itl
import random
import time

from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

import Levenshtein as pylev
import pandas as pd


def lev_distance_matrix(seqs):
    """Calculate Levenshtein distance and ratio metrics
       on input pair of strings.
    """
    seqs = sorted(seqs)

    return {
        seqs[0]: {
            seqs[1]: {
                "distance": pylev.distance(*seqs),
                "ratio": pylev.ratio(*seqs),
            }
        }
    }


t_init = time.time()

print(
    f"\n:::------|Levenshteins|----->__BEGIN__:::\n\t\t@{t_init} s"
)


seqs = sorted(
    [
        "".join(random.choices(DNA, k=random.randint(12, 16)))
        for _ in range(20)
    ]
)

all_seq_pairs = set(
    sorted(
        list(
            itl.chain.from_iterable(
                [[(s1, s2) for s1 in seqs] for s2 in seqs]
            )
        )
    )
)

print("\n".join(seqs))
print(len(all_seq_pairs))

seq_sim_results = list(map(lev_distance_matrix, all_seq_pairs))

chain_r = defaultdict(lambda: {})
for n, r in enumerate(seq_sim_results):
    for i, (k1, v1) in enumerate(r.items()):
        for j, (k2, v2) in enumerate(v1.items()):
            chain_r[k1][k2] = v2["ratio"]
            chain_r[k2][k1] = v2["ratio"]


print(
    f"\n:::------|Levenshteins|----->_COMPLETE_:::\n\t\tRequired {time.time() - t_init} s"
)
```

```
:::------|Levenshteins|----->__BEGIN__:::
        @1690901349.5007648 s
AAGCATGTAGTCC
ACAGCCGCTTAT
AGCGTCGCGCAGG
AGTCCCTTCGGTT
AGTCGCTTCGTA
ATATCGACGTGGCAT
ATATCTAGTGTCTC
CCTTTAGTACTTG
CGTCTCGTGGCA
CTCTCCAAATGTCTA
CTTATTTCGGGC
GCCAGGCCGGTCGA
GCCTTAATCCCCA
GCGATTGGGCTATA
GGCCTGAGTAAGTTTG
GTATCCTTCGTAAG
GTCTTTACTTGTC
GTTCGGAGATAGCCA
TCCAATGGGCCACT
TCCTGAAAATCAAGGG
400


:::------|Levenshteins|----->_COMPLETE_:::
        Required 0.003915071487426758 s
```

```py
import seaborn as sns

df_ratios = pd.DataFrame(chain_r).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)

sns.heatmap(df_ratios)
```

[image: heatmap of ratios]